# Translate content on attachment pages – what am I missing?

Tags: php, wordpress, qtranslate

I want to use the qTranslate-Translation on [this page](http://luisleu.de/en/galerie-ahnen-3-03/) as on any other with the names of the "Previous" and "Next" links. Somehow it doesn't work and for hours I have tried to figure out why...

It *should* use either the German or the English words depending on the chosen language – as it does on any other language. In the settings of qTranslate "attachments" is obviously checked for translation.

It somehow recognises the tags, that way it doesn't display just the whole thing as a string, but just the two words next to each other.

Maybe someone with eagle's eyes? Thanks!

```
...
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>

<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

    <div class="grid_12 exhibition-views">

        <div class="navigation">
            <div class="previous">
                <?php 
                    _e("[:en]".previous_image_link(0,'Previous')."[:de]".previous_image_link(0,'Zurück')."[:]");
                ?>
            </div>
            <div class="next">
                <?php 
                    _e("[:en]".next_image_link(0,'Next')."[:de]".next_image_link(0,'Weiter')."[:]");
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, 'large' ); ?>

        <!-- <div class="caption">< ?php if ( !empty($post->post_excerpt) ) the_excerpt(); ? ></div> -->

    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your code, you're expecting `next_image_link` to return a string.  It doesn't - it `echo`s the link.  See [the source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4.2/src/wp-includes/media.php#L2605) - `next_image_link` calls `adjacent_image_link`, which does the echo on line 2658.

How about doing:

```
next_image_link(0,__('[:en]Next[:de]Weiter[:]'));
```

instead?

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Only remaining problem I have now is that image.php somehow pulls also the general image that is being used by Facebook as link-post image [id=183] (click 'previous' [here](http://luisleu.de/galerie-ahnen-3-01/) until it appears). I want to generally exclude this image from image slideshows. I tried to put query_post in front but that seems to break the whole functionality. Maybe I could edit the source code of [wp_get_attachment_image](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_attachment_image/) to enable 'exclude' as an attribute of the template tag?